# Determining how often each element appears in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Is there an efficient C algorithm to compute and report the number of equal elements in an array

For example, if we have

```
int Z[] = { 4, 9, 4, 10, 4, 2,  10, 1, 19, 21, 21 };
```

then the result should be

```
elem         number
  4            3
  9            1
  10           2
  2            1
  1            1
  19           1
  21           2
```

Comment: Yes, I thought. I don't agree with you that is stupid question. Think about for example 'dutch national flag problem'

Comment: where have you seen that I told that this is a stupid question? How is your flag problem has anything to do with this?

Comment: Your declamation was very ironic. Flag problem is very sofisticated way to solve problem and I'd like to know is there any efficient algorithm to solve my  question. simply

Comment: Will try to approach it from a different way. You basically ask how to solve a simple problem in an efficient way. Look at your problem: efficient with respect to what? What is your the algorithm that you do not find efficient enough? Why is not it efficient? If I will ask you: **I have two numbers `a` and `b`. Have mathematicians come up with efficient algorithm to solve this?** What would be your answer?

Comment: If the possible range of ints is small (e.g. not more than 100000) then there is a very simple solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you can do this, each of which has different performance tradeoffs.

First, you could just do a double for-loop over the array and, for each element, count how many times it appears. This will take time O(n<sup>2</sup>), where n is the number of array elements. However, it only requires space O(1).

Second, you could sort the array into ascending order, which will group together identical elements. From there, it's easy to see how many times each element appears, since you can iterate across the array once and count up how many consecutive times each element appears. The runtime and space used depends on how you sort the array. If you use heapsort, the runtime will be O(n log n) and the space usage will only be O(1). If you happen to know all the elements in the array range from 0 to U inclusive, you can use counting sort in time O(n + U) and space O(U) or radix sort in time O(n log U) and space O(n).

Third, you could build an auxiliary table storing the frequencies of each element and populate it by iterating across the array once, filling in the entries as you go. If you use a hash table, the expected runtime will be O(n) and the space usage will be O(n) as well. If you know the array elements are in the range 0 to U, inclusive, you could just use a frequency array and solve this in time O(n + U) and space O(U) (which, essentially, would be counting sort!)

There's no clear winner here. Heapsort has the best time complexity for something with O(1) space usage. Hashing has the best overall time complexity but poor space usage. Counting or radix sort might be best depending on how big the numbers can get.

Based on your situation, take a look at what your actual parameters are and hopefully you can choose whichever solution is best for you in the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer that works.

The first loop initializes the count of numbers array to all zeros.

The second loop scans through all your numbers until it reaches number zero then the scan stops. Nice thing about this method is you can add a bunch of numbers that are not zero in-between to make your array larger and the program would still work.

Finally, the third loop just goes through the count of numbers array and prints results in a nicely sorted fashion.

In the array of predefined numbers, do not remove the zero and re-run the program or you will get unexpected results which could include segmentation fault.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
      int Z[] = { 4, 9, 4, 10, 4, 2,  10, 1, 19, 21, 21, 0};
      int n;
      int lowest=1;
      int highest=100;
      int counts[highest+1];
      for (n=0;n<=highest;n++){
        counts[n]=0;
      }
      int *num=Z;
      while((int)*num != 0){
        counts[*num]++;
        num++;
      }

      for (n=lowest;n<=highest;n++){
        if (counts[n] > 0){
          printf("%d = %d\n",n,counts[n]);
        }
      }
      return 0;
    }
```